# Longtables on a page and overflow to multiple pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I have two longtables I want to keep them vertically on a single page, but the second one is too long that it has to span on next page. I have tried:

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{guide_table_1.tex}
% 
\vspace{3em}
% 
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{guide_table_2.tex}

\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
```

But minipage doesn't do page break. Otherwise, first table will push the second one to a new page. Is there a way `tcolorbox` or somehow to keep both satisfied?

Example:

[image: two tables lay vertically on a single page, and the second overflows]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up is a bit confusing: You appear to say that you want to keep the two table-like items on a single page, side by side, but also that one of items does *not* fit on a single page. Is the first objective simply not attainable? Please clarify. Please also confirm the impression that your document uses a two-column layout. If that's the case, though, why are you using a `table*` environment, which spans the width of both columns (and, incidentally, can also not spill over across pages)?

Comment: @Mico the two tables lay as paragraphs, the document layout I want is single column. Something like the snapshot I posted. The difficulty I encountered is to keep both on the same page while spans the second one. Without `table*` env I haven't figured out a way to force them to one page. Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: So what's the preferred treatment of the right-hand (the one that spills over to the next age? Should it be full-width or, if the same width as on the first page, should it be placed at the left or right? And, what's supposed to be going on on the remainder of the second page? Blank, ordinary material, or something else?

Comment: @Mico it's supposed to be kept in the same position as in the first page, and on the second page it's only the rest of the overflowing table. I'm checking `listoftables` with `[!h]`, which seems to be a solution.

Comment: it is very hard to understand your question (it _always_ helps if you provide an example document) but certainly never put longtable inside a table or minipage environment. You should be able just to use two longtables one after the other to get what you describe.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle use one after another pushed the second to a single page (floating). I need a `[!h]` fixed position option for `\LTXtable` or `longtable`.

Comment: @knh190 sorry your comment does not make sense! longtables do not float and have no `[!h]` argument. Please make a small test document that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle alright, clean longtables simply don't float. I didn't get the right question. Thanks for that!